# Node-By-Node XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I need to write out an XML where the order of elements is important (I realize that XML format might not be the right thing to use here, but...). I need something like:

```
<Author>
<Book>
<Author>
<Book>
```

The underlying class has elements that look like:

```
Author[] Author;
Book[] Book;
```

I am planning on having an index value on the Book and Author classes and using that to write out the XML.

What I am trying to find is if there is an easy way to serialize classes one by one into an XML. I looked at XmlWriter but it looks like it can only be used to write XML at a very basic level (i.e. no serialization support).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the built-in serialization routines (and sometimes you don't, because your structure may change and it gets harder and harder to use those routines as your structure evolves over time), then an easy way to get where you want to go is to create an **XmlDocument** and then use **XmlDocument.CreateNode** to create an XML node for the document, adding attributes to the node as needed, then add the node to the document using **XmlDocument.AppendChild** (or as you get deeper into the structure, use **XmlNode.AppendChild**).  Finally, use **XmlDocument.Save** to write the structure out to a file (or memory or whatever you want to do with it at that point).

The Microsoft [System.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace documentation is quite good, look to there for a lot of examples and then just write quick test programs to verify what you learn from the examples.